# jquerymobile session timeout with 2 timers

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, timeout

Edit: I see the issue is with using live instead of on. I fixed that however, can't get the second timer to fire..

Error: `Object [object Object] has no method "popup"`

I am trying to implement a client side session time out using jquery mobile. My code is at: http://jsfiddle.net/83BSW/5

Appreciate any insights..

Here is the code for convenience:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>


<!-- Application specific -->

<script> 
var first_timer = 2 * 1000;
var second_timer = 3 * 1000;
var down = -1;

function initTimer() {
  down = setTimeout(processTimeout, first_timer)
}

function processTimeout() {
        down = setTimeout(logout, second_timer);
        $.mobile.changePage('#timeout1',{transition:'slide', role:'dialog'});
        //alert ("Timeout of first timer, timerid:" + down );
}

function logout() {
    $("#timeout").popup('close');
  $.mobile.changePage('#timeout2',{transition:'slide', role:'dialog'});
  alert("You are logged out");
//  window.location = "http://www.google.com"
}

function resetMyTimer() {
  if ( -1 != down )
    clearTimeout(down);
  alert("Restarting timer");
  initTimer();
}

$("#loadingpage").on(function() {
    resetMyTimer();
});

initTimer();

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="loadingpage">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"> 
      <div class="headerlogo"> </div>
      <h1> Test </h1>
  </div> 
  <div data-role="content" >
    <div id="ssagov"> 
    <h1> Hi there </h1>
    </div> 
    <input type="button" data-shadow="false" data-corners="false" value="Next"  />
  </div><!-- /content --> 
</div><!-- /launch page -->
<div data-role="page" id="timeout1" data-role="popup">
  <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
    <h1>Timeout1</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    Your session will timeout in 2 mins.
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="timeout2" data-role="popup">
  <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
    <h1>Timeout2</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    Your session has timed out
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: hmm, looks like I should use 'on' instead of 'live'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue, instead of popup, I should be using dialog. Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/83BSW/6